# can't pass id to page product in nextjs 13's dynamic segments: "params is not defined"

Tags: reactjs, next.js

i have to display some articles in my website and i have the data of each article stored in a simple array of objects in a typescript file like this example:

```
magazines.ts

const magazines = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "Blue",
    body: "lorem ipsum...",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "Red",
    pic: "lorem ipsum...",
  },
];

export default magazines;
```

this is the folder structure:

```
app
└──service-clients
    └──magazine
       └──MagazineUI.js
       └──page.js
       └──[magazineId]
           └──page.js
```

and i have them displayed all together in the service-clients/magazine page path like this:

```
magazine/page.js


import React from "react";
import MagazineUI from "./MagazineUI.js";

import magazines from "../../../magazines.ts";

const page = () => {
  return (
    <main>
      <section className="w-[90%] m-auto md:w-[100%]">
        <div>
          {magazines.map((magazine) => (
            <MagazineUI magazine={magazine} />
          ))}
        </div>
      </section>
    </main>
  );
};

export default page;
```

and then i used the MagazineUI component for each of their interfaces:

```
magazine/magazineUI.js

import Link from "next/link";
import React from "react";

const Magazine = ({ magazine }) => {
  return (
    <Link
      href="service-clients/magazine/[magazineId]"
      as={`service-clients/magazine/${magazine.id}`}
      className="mb-[20px]"
    >
      <div>
        <p className="font-work text-[1.2rem]">{magazine.title}</p>
        <p className="font-work text-[1.2rem]">{magazine.body}</p>
      </div>
    </Link>
  );
};

export default Magazine;
```

and it works so far.
**Now i have to display each of these articles/magazines in one page with their own ids through the [magazineID] dynamic segment but i keep getting the error "params is not defined" when i go to service-clients/magazine/1**

here's the code, can anybody fix it?

```
magazine/[magazineId]/page.js

import React from "react";

import magazines from "../../../../magazines.ts";

function PageMagazines({ params: { magazineId } }) {
  const magazine = magazines.find((magazine) => {
    return magazine.id === params.magazineId;
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{magazine.title}</p>
      <p>{magazine.body}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default PageMagazines;
```

Comment: Where do `params`  come from?

Comment: @Konrad idk honestly..  i've been helping myself with the nextjs docs and i copied it from there but i'm not sure about anything i wrote in the last page.js file, it's probably all wrong 

Comment: Please post a link to a place where you found it

Comment: @Konrad here:) https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/routing/defining-routes#dynamic-segments

Answer (score 0):

In the [link you posted](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/routing/defining-routes#dynamic-segments) there is:

> See the [generateStaticParams()](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/data-fetching/generating-static-params) page to learn how to generate the params for the segment.

In [Generating Static Params](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/data-fetching/generating-static-params) you can see example code:

```
export async function generateStaticParams() {
  const posts = await getPosts();

  return posts.map((post) => ({
    slug: post.slug,
  }));
}
```

You probably want something like `magazineId` and not `slug`

Comment: how do i write the getPosts function ?

Comment: I guess that for you it will be just `magazines`